# What is the difference between head(10) and [:10] in pyhton?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, select

I am newbie. Instructor said ı am going to select first ten then he write the code below.

`df['Runtime'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False)[:10]`

I tried the code `df['Runtime'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False)[:10]` it gives me different result. What's the fundamental difference between the two different expressions?

```
df['Runtime'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False)[:10]
90.0    971
95.0    489
92.0    434
93.0    422
85.0    408
       ... 
19.0      8
32.0      8
9.0       8
7.0       8
10.0      8
Name: Runtime, Length: 157, dtype: int64

.
df['Runtime'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).head(10)
90.0     971
95.0     489
92.0     434
93.0     422
85.0     408
89.0     407
88.0     406
100.0    402
91.0     394
94.0     383
Name: Runtime, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the output of `[:10]` and not *all* results?

Comment: yes ı am sure this is the results of all df['Runtime'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False)
90.0     971
95.0     489
92.0     434
93.0     422
85.0     408
        ... 
227.0      1
191.0      1
224.0      1
410.0      1
233.0      1
Name: Runtime, Length: 225, dtype: int64

Comment: What you wrote in the comment returns *all* the results. Not just the first 10

Comment: It may be misunderstood, but I wanted to show the result of the unfiltered version in the comment I just sent . Above is the result of [:10] .

Comment: I can replicate this (when the values of Runtime are floats, like yours are)

Answer (score 1):

#### Why the surprising results?

Because the `Runtime` column in your DataFrame is of float datatype, the result of `value_counts()` is a Series with an index of type `Float64Index`.

The behaviour of `[ ]` style indexing on a series with a `Float64Index` is [quirky. See this GitHub issue discussion:](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7501#issuecomment-331985174)

> To summarize in a specific way [...] for all index types, using integers in `[]` (`__getitem__`) is positional (like `iloc`), except for `Float64Index`, making this a special case.

Essentially, with a float index, `[:10]` is interpreted **not** as "the first ten values" but as "all the values until the one where the index value is 10.0".

With your data, that's why you see `df['Runtime'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False)[:10]` giving 157 rows, with the last row having an index value of 10.0.

---

#### Getting the behaviour you want

To get the first ten values like you want, you can do:

`df['Runtime'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).iloc[:10]`

or equivalently:

`df['Runtime'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).head(10)`

(Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L5559-L5632) shows that `.head(n)` returns the result of `.iloc[:n]`.)

---

#### How to reproduce

We don't have access to your data, so here's a quick script I made to produce a similar enough DataFrame to reproduce the issue.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(5678)
vals = np.random.randint(0, 50, size=1000).astype(float)
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=['Runtime'])

s = df['Runtime'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False)
s[:10]   # produces 32 rows, the last one with index 10.0
s.iloc[:10]  # the first 10 rows
s.head(10)   # also the first 10 rows
```